# Magnetic field from vector potential

Tags: vectors, electromagnetism

How do you find the magnetic field from knowing the vector potential?

I have the vector potential:

$\vec{A}(x,y)=\frac{\mu_0Ixy}{\pi a^2}$

And have been asked to find the magnetic field which I happen to know is

$\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0I}{\pi a^2}\rho(\cos{2\psi}\vec\rho - \sin2\psi\vec\psi$ (in cylindrical coordinates)

where $\vec\rho,\vec\psi$ are unit vectors.

My question is how do you get from the magnetic potential to magnetic potential

Comment: Isn't the field just partial differentiation of given potential w.r.t x and y? U get uI(x+y)/(pi.a^2) .

Answer (score 1):

By calculating the curl

$$\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$$

BTW, this question probably suits more [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).